# How to stop execution of some code to stop its execution immediate in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I have library that can run for up to 30 minutes or even more.

In my client code i want to have opportunity to stop working of library's instance; Hot can i do it?

For example

```
 public class TickMe
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("tik" + i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And client code:

```
public class Client
{
  protected TickMe instance;
  public void Run()
  {
     TickMe instance = new TickMe();
     instance.Run();
  }

  public void Kill()
  {
    instance?????
  }
}
```

So what code i need to put in method Kill() to stop working instance of class TickMe ?

Comment: Your `Run()` method currently blocks the thread. Convert it to an `async` method, replace` Thread.Sleep()` with `await Task.Delay()` and learn how to use a CancellationToken that you'd pass to the `Run()` method and cancel it using the client.

Comment: You need some mechanism to stop the while-loop.

Comment: Ideally, work with the library authors so that they add support for *cooperative* cancellation via `CancellationToken`. The alternatively, when you yank the rug out from under the library when it has no idea that could happen can lead to... tricky to diagnose issues later. The library *could* be doing practically anything, including stuff that it only intends to *temporarily* change and you stop it being able to revert those changes

Comment: Thank u guys, i know about cancelation token and about that tasks. But  loop can take like 10 minutes each. Even if i put "token.IsCancellationRequested" in end of my loop  - i have to wait 10 minutes anyway. But i want immediate stop solution.

Comment: Can you make changes to `TickMe.Run` at all? If not theres basically nothing you can do to stop it running. Also your `Client.Run` method has a local variable `instance` which is completely separate from your class-level variable making it inaccessible outside that method (But im guessing this is a typo)

Comment: Also "Even if i put "token.IsCancellationRequested" in end of my loop - i have to wait 10 minutes anyway." - then put it in _multiple_ places in the loop. Theres nothing that says you can only call that once per loop.

Comment: Well, the alternative is [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=net-5.0) but notice all of the warnings (and lack of support on .NET 5, etc). People have discovered the hard way that doing it non-cooperatively opens up a world of pain.

Comment: Active cancellation requires your process to _support_ cancellation either in the form of a simple boolean flag or you can use cancellation tokens. Simple check the token at every opportunity before starting the next long running sub-process. If there is no direct feedback, then you could try passive cancel, execute your loop logic in another container, thread space or even process, then you could simple _kill_ the process that is executing your code. It's a strange anti-pattern, but could be done. Maybe explore why you want to cancel at all, there might be different ways to mitigate the need.

Comment: Thank u! im wondering what if i use ProcessStartInfo? So i can kill that process in seconds, if i want?

Comment: I don't know why no one has mentioned the fact that this exact question has a full answer in Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children

Comment: TJ Rockefeller, i know about parallel programming or tasks. I want to stop my program immediate, without waiting any time. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something that doesn't block the current thread and to exit the while-loop.

You could try something like this:

```
public class TickMe
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public async Task Start()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        int i = 0;
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("tik" + i);
            i++;
        }

        _cancellationTokenSource = null;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    protected TickMe _instance;

    public async Task Run()
    {
        _instance = new TickMe();
        await _instance.Start();
    }

    public void Kill()
    {
        _instance.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better: Pass the token in from the calling client - it may itself have received one rather than create one internally

Comment: @Jamiec If the client has a CancellationToken, I'd rather advise to use a `CreateLinkedTokenSource` to link them, so the TickMe can be cancelled without cancelling the Client, but still able to have a cascade effect on stopping the client and tickme directly. (so the comment "Pass the token in from the calling client" still stands with a little modification)

Comment: Looks nice! But anyway, if my loop takes like 10 minutes, i have to wait it. But i want to stop it when i request it.

Comment: @ssrdop You could move the while-loop to a `Task.Run(() => ....)`, or just not await the `_ = Run();`

Comment: Yeah it only was example. In real i have library that have loop. Sure i can edit that library to add some tokens, but the problem is i want to stop it immediatly. Thank u for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's make your tick asyncronous, to not block the current thread:

```
 public class TickMe
    {
        private int _counter;
        private object locker = new object();

        public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancelationToken)
        {
            _counter = 0;
            while (!cancelationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(200);
                Console.WriteLine("tik" + _counter);
                lock (locker)
                {
                    _counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- Note the use of CancellationToken to stop the execution.
- Note the use of lock to deal with the counter.

Then we create a CancellationToken to stop the execution of your asyncronous method, and pass it as parameter for the function on the main method and it's ready to go

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancelationToken = source.Token;

            var tick = new TickMe();

            Task.Run(async () => await tick.Run(cancelationToken));

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("foo");

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            source.Cancel();

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("bar");
        }
    }
```

The results should be closer to this:

```
tik0
tik1
tik2
tik3
tik4
tik5
tik6
tik7
tik8
foo
tik9
tik10
tik11
tik12
tik13
bar
```